# Отключение возможности перематывать аудиозапись

Tags: javascript, html5, аудио

В общем ситуация такая: 
Есть `audio` в котором музыка. Человек нажимает на кнопку и аудио запускается. Суть в том, что мне нужно сделать, что бы пользователь не мог перемотать аудио.

Я пробовал убрать `controls`, скрыть плеер, но это же бесполезно. Пользователь всё равно может зайти, найти`audio`, добавить в DOM `controls`, убрать стиль скрывающий плеер.

Можно ли как-то выкрутиться?

Comment: Пользователь достанет из монитора сети прямую ссылку, откроет её за пределами браузера в своём любимом плеере и всё равно перемотает :)

Comment: @andreymal, мне главное что бы у меня на сайте не перематывалось :) Я игру делаю, в которой звук играет одну из важнейших ролей)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все можно решить достаточно просто: закодируйте аудио файл постоянным битрейтом и отдавайте его с этой скоростью. Но тут пользователь все равно сможет дождаться загрузки и перемотать, просто займет это то же время, что прослушать в приложении.

Answer (score 4):

Вообще, единственный вариант, который я вижу - это воспроизводить аудио через `js` не внося его в дом.

```js
var audio = document.createElement('audio');
audio.setAttribute('src', 'https://zf.fm/download/3860794');

var button = document.querySelector('button');

button.status = false;

button.onclick = function() {
  if( this.status == false ){
    this.innerHTML = 'Pause';
    audio.play();
    this.status = true;
  }else{
    this.innerHTML = 'Play';
    audio.pause();
    this.status = false;
  };
};
```

```html
<button>Play</button>
```

Но это всё равно вариант ненадёжный

Comment: Если завернуть объект audio в замыкание, то извне к нему не пробраться и станет уже довольно неплохо

Comment: А кто помешает разобрать скрипт, отредактировать и запустить? Если конечный пользователь умеет через консоль править DooM, то и с этим справится.

Comment: @Other, ну вряд ли все будут лесть в DooM что бы перемотать аудио-файл :)

Comment: Тогда можно вообще не парится на эту тему. Просто убрать элементы и всё: кому надо - скачают и перемотают, остальным и этого хватит.

Comment: @andreymal даже через Network из Devtools?

Comment: @SashaOmelchenko как отметил автор в комментарии, ему это не столь важно, да и тоже решается на самом деле)

Comment: @andreymal, и как будет выглядеть решение такого ограничения?

Comment: @VostokSisters, давно тебя не видел )

Comment: @Yuri, ну в вопросах мог бы уже давно заметить) Довольно много активничаю в последнее время. Продолжаю работу над сайтиком.

Comment: @VostokSisters в соседнем ответе вариант, например

Comment: @andreymal, а по окончанию загрузки, что, не будет его видно через панель разработчика? Мне кажется будет.

Comment: @VostokSisters если я правильно понял автора, к тому моменту перематывать будет уже бессмысленно)